# Как проитерироваться по вложенному словарю?

Tags: python, python-3.x, словари, python-unittest

Не могу проверить обязательное заполнение ключей key1, key2, key3, key4.

словарь:
`{ "global_key1": { "key1": "value1", "key2": "value2" }, "global_key2": { "key3": "value3", "key4": "value4" } }`

Comment: Приведите примеры работы)

Comment: get-ом проверяйте: `my_dict['global_key1'].get('key1')`

Comment: [Чтобы поблагодарить автора ответа](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers), проголосуйте за ответ и отметьте его [галочкой](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) как решение.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно просто с помощью `for` проитерироваться по значениям словаря (где каждое значение - вложенный словарь), в каждом вложенном словаре проверить наличие нужных ключей:

```
for subdict in d.values():
    for key in ['key1', 'key2', 'key3', 'key4']:
        assert subdict.get(key) is not None
```

`assert` написал в pytest-стиле, на unittest будет примерно так:

```
self.assertIsNotNone(subdict.get(key))
```

Comment: а если данные значения(сам словарь) лежит в отдельном json файле?

Comment: @Maksim прочитайте файл, переведите в словарь